# FIND Highest Value From Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to increment tax_invoice_number each time when record is created. The pattern of tax_invoice_number saved is in this form "IN2015-000001". when  new record  is created it should be "IN2015-000002".

**Scenario 1:**

```
key = "IN2015"

max = TaxInvoice.where("tax_invoice_number like ?", "%#{key}%").max_by(&:tax_invoice_number)

unless max.nil?
  increment = max.tax_invoice_number.split('-')[-1].to_i + 1
else
  increment = "000001"   #For First Record
end

tax_invoice_number = key + "-" + (sprintf "%06d",increment)
```

While doing this i found one problem that is if suppose i have two tax_invoice_numbers i,e **"IN2015-999999" and "IN2015-1000000"** and when i do above operation i get 
**max = "IN2015-999999"** #which should not be as **"IN2015-1000000"** is greater, as we are saving tax_invoice_number as string "IN2015-999999" is greater.

So to avoid that

Scenario 2

```
key = "IN2015"

max = TaxInvoice.where("tax_invoice_number like ?", "%#{key}%").map{|x| x.tax_invoice_number.split('-').last.to_i }.max

unless max.nil?
  increment = max + 1
else
  increment = "000001"   #For First Record
end

tax_invoice_number = key + "-" + (sprintf "%06d",increment)
```

Here i am getting correct output no problem.

Is there any better solution like:

```
TaxInvoice.maximum("tax_invoice_number")
```

I cant do this as my tax_invoice_number is string in table and i cant change my migration. If i do this TaxInvoice.maximum("tax_invoice_number") again this "IN2015-999999" will come maximum then "IN2015-1000000"

Comment: You should increase the size of zero-pad for your invoice numbers. If it's "IN2015-00999999", it will be sorted correctly, compared to "IN2015-01000000" (see, I left some room for growth?)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot migrate your DB because it's an old system, but still I suggest you to have a pure integer ID value and maybe a function to create your full invoice number.

In your model (untested code):

```
class TaxInvoice

  after_create :generate_invoice_number

  def generate_invoice_number
    max_id = # Find the max invoice number of the current year, if no value, make it be 0.
    self.tax_invoice_number = "IN#{Date.today.strftime('%Y')}-#{max_id + 1}"
    self.save
  end

end
```

**EDIT:** It will create the year according the date at the moment of creation.

**EDIT 2:** If you want to reset the number when the year changes, then you definitely need another value apart from ID to define this. It seems autoincrement is not included in Rails and it would depend on the database, unless you use another callback. 
The last thing you need is to make the search by year so you get the last invoice.

Comment: Ya your solution is correct but there is one condition that is if it goes to next year then it should reset to IN2016-000001

Comment: I edited with some clarifications. It is not as simple solution as it might seem, you need to make some choices here.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
def generate_tax_invoice_number 
   #generate auto-increment tax_invoice_number for tax_invoices
   self.tax_invoice_number = "#{IN}#{Date.today.strftime('%Y%m%d')}-#{next_val}"
end

def next_val
   key = "#{IN}#{Date.today.strftime('%Y%m')}"
   sprintf("%06d", (TaxInvoice.where("tax_invoice_number like ?", "%#{key}%").map{|x| x.tax_invoice_number.split('-').last.to_i }.max || 0) + 1)
end
```

Comment: This is same as scenario 2